# perl multi line comments are not aligned properly

Tags: normal-mode, alignment

With Vim 7.2, when a perl block is aligned using `=`, 
Multi line comments are moved as per the blocks inner alignment. But they should be placed at immediate start of the line.
Is there any way to solve this.

Executing

```
    :%s/^\s\+=/=/g
```

every time is time consuming.

Example file:

```
 if($i==0)
 {
 $i=$i+3;
  =head
  This part can be optimised
  =cut
 print $i;
 }
```

After aligning (with <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>)

```
   if($i==0)
  {
       $i=$i+3;
       =head
      This part can be optimised
      =cut
     print $i;
   }
```

Expected alignment;

```
   if($i==0)
   {
         $i=$i+3;
   =head
   This part can be optimised
   =cut
        print $i;
   }
```

Comment: What version of Vim are you using? What does `set equalprg?` say in a buffer with a Perl file?

Comment: Version 7.2. When I entered set equalprg, it shows equalprg= (blank)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was fixed with [an update to `runtime/indent/perl.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/9de999794999de1ccd3d743a2d5b361e5ce19273#diff-b506883eec17ba92662bbe9b001626ff) for 7.4: they reworked the indentation logic for heredocs and stuff that follows it.

You can [download the file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim/vim/9de999794999de1ccd3d743a2d5b361e5ce19273/runtime/indent/perl.vim) and put it into `~/.vim/after/indent/perl.vim` (or into correspoding global dir).

Comment: The comments are aligned properly. But the lines following it are also aligned to left edge of the screen. Expected is, the following lines has to be aligned based on it's parent block

Comment: Ooops... I'm guilty of modifying your code (put it inside a `sub`.) How about [this version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim/vim/543b7ef7000d08d77409478315d68b607bb8bad8/runtime/indent/perl.vim)? Seem to work here.

Comment: Anyhow, the versions you provided work only for multiline comments outside any blocks. They aren't aligning multiline comments inside a block. Solution must be universal for any perl script.

Comment: Vim doesn't align them because POD blocks can't be aligned: `=` should be right at the start of the line. `perlpod` doesn't say so quite as explicitly, stating that "All command paragraphs […] start with `=`" instead, but [this thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=560924) at PerlMonks discusses the limitation (search for "indent", there's a few subthreads about it.)